# Make 2 changes with 4 changes

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

With the numbers 2, 0, 2, 0, use four changes to make two changes. From two changes, use three changes to make zero change.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done to these numbers by

> a) writing in the order 2 0 0 2
>  b) then four changes to SWOP - a variant spelling of swap - is two changes
>  c) then three changes to STOP, meaning no more change.
>
>  [image]

Comment: You're right that it's rot13(flzobyvp genafsbezngvbaf), but it's not in rot13(qvtvgny sbag)